# SQL Server : query to insert data into table from another table with different struct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in two different databases.

My first table is an older version and has fewer columns than the second table.

I want to copy the contents of my old table to my new table.

In each database table there are several distribution in this case.

How can I do to quickly copy data from old tables to the new without having to write the column names manually for each table?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the columns in the new table only appended on the end?

Comment: Nop anywhere.
 And the database source and destination is not same.
Table 1 is in database 1 and table 2 is in database 2

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following  code should do the work.
Basically what it does is:

*1. Collects column names from both tables.

 2. Intersects the column names in order to filter out columns that exists only in 1 table.

 3. Get a string which is the column names delimited by a comma.

 4. Using the string from stage #3 creating the insert command.

 5. Executing the command from stage #4.*

```
--BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @oldName NVARCHAR(50) = 'OldTableName', @newName NVARCHAR(50) = 'newTableName'
DECLARE @oldDBName NVARCHAR(50) = '[OldDBName].[dbo].['+@oldName+']', @newDBName NVARCHAR(50) = '[newDBName].[dbo].['+@newName+']'

/*This table variable will have columns that exists in both table*/
DECLARE @tCommonColumns TABLE(
ColumnsName NVARCHAR(max) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @tCommonColumns

SELECT column_name --,*
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = @oldName
AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(@oldName), column_name, 'IsIdentity') = 0 --this will make sure you ommit IDentity columns

INTERSECT

SELECT column_name --, *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = @newName
AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(@newName), column_name,'IsIdentity') = 0--this will make sure you ommit IDentity columns

--SELECT * FROM @tCommonColumns

/*Get the columns as a comma seperated string */
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(max)
SELECT DISTINCT 
                @columns  = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cols.ColumnsName
                                    FROM @tCommonColumns cols

                                      FOR XML Path('')),1,1,'')
FROM @tCommonColumns
PRINT @columns 
/*Create tyhe insert command*/
DECLARE @InserCmd NVARCHAR(max)
SET @InserCmd = 
'INSERT INTO '+@newDBName +' ('+@columns +')
SELECT '+@columns +' FROM '+@oldDBName

PRINT @InserCmd
/*Execute the command*/
EXECUTE sp_executesql @InserCmd
--ROLLBACK
```

Please note that this script might fail if you have [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx) That are fulfiled in the old table but not in the new table.

**Edit:**
The query was updated to omit [`Identity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) columns.

**Edit 2:**
query updated for supporting different databases for the tables (make sure you set the `@oldName` ,`@newName`, `@oldDBName`, `@newDBName` variables to match actual credentials).

Comment: @BenjaminCEREDE Please take a look at the updated script. It now supports different databases for the tables (make sure you set the `@oldName`,`@newName`,`@oldDBName`,`@newDBName` variables to match your actual credentials).

Comment: Ok thanks !
But
SELECT column_name --,*
FROM information_schema.columns
Return null because not database specified and run query in master

Comment: @BenjaminCEREDE Well, if it is a one time thing, just make it less generic and write it down specifically...

Comment: Ok. It's possible to add NOT NULLABLE fileds of new table with '' value ?

Comment: @BenjaminCEREDE, I suggest you set this value to be the default value of the column. It will have the desired effect.

Comment: It may be that he doesn't want to skip the identity column. Instead, `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TableName] ON` might be exactly what he needs!

Answer (score 1):

You can "avoid writing the column names manually" in SSMS by dragging and dropping the "Columns" folder under the table in the Object Explorer over to a query window (just hold the dragged item over whitespace or the character position where you want the names to appear). All the column names will be displayed separated by commas.

[image: SSMS Table Columns folder]

You could also try something like this to get just the list of columns that are common between two tables (then writing the INSERT statement is trivial).

```
SELECT
   Substring((
      SELECT
         ', ' + S.COLUMN_NAME
      FROM
         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS S
         INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS D
            ON S.COLUMN_NAME = D.COLUMN_NAME
      WHERE
         S.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
         AND S.TABLE_NAME = 'Source Table'
         AND D.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
         AND D.TABLE_NAME = 'Destination Table'
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 3, 21474783647)
;
```

You could also create an SSIS package that simply moves all the data from one table to the other. Column names that match would automatically be linked up. Depending on your familiarity with SSIS, this could take you 2 minutes, or it could take you 2 hours.

Comment: What database should I put to attack both at the same time?

Comment: Are the databases on the same server? If so, just use 3-part naming (`Database.Schema.Table`). If the databases are on different servers, then you can just use 4-part naming after adding a linked server from one database to the other (`LinkedServer.Database.Schema.Table`). If you have problems joining across the linked server, `SELECT` the remote data to a local temp table first, then `JOIN` afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all !

I propose that it's more generic :)

```
--BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @Tablename NVARCHAR(50)
SET @Tablename = 'tableName'

DECLARE @Schemaname NVARCHAR(50)
SET @Schemaname = 'schemaName'

DECLARE @Datasource NVARCHAR(50)
SET @Datasource = 'dataSource'

DECLARE @Datadest NVARCHAR(50)
SET @Datadest = 'dataDestination'

/*This table variable will have columns that exists in both table*/
DECLARE @tCommonColumns TABLE(
ColumnsName NVARCHAR(max) NOT NULL
);

--INSERT INTO @tCommonColumns
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT column_name
            FROM ' + @Datasource + '.information_schema.columns
            WHERE table_name = ''' + @Tablename + '''
            AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(''' + @Datasource + '.' + @Schemaname + '.' + @Tablename + '''), column_name, ''IsIdentity'') = 0' --this will make sure you ommit IDentity columns

SET @sql = @sql + ' INTERSECT
            SELECT column_name
            FROM ' + @Datadest + '.information_schema.columns
            WHERE table_name = ''' + @Tablename + '''
            AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(''' + @Datadest + '.' + @Schemaname + '.' + @Tablename + '''), column_name, ''IsIdentity'') = 0' --this will make sure you ommit IDentity columns'

INSERT INTO @tCommonColumns EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

-- SELECT * FROM @tCommonColumns

/*Get the columns as a comma seperated string */
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(max)
SELECT DISTINCT 
                @columns  = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cols.ColumnsName
                                    FROM @tCommonColumns cols

                                      FOR XML Path('')),1,1,'')
FROM @tCommonColumns
--PRINT @columns 
/*Create tyhe insert command*/
DECLARE @InserCmd NVARCHAR(max)
SET @InserCmd = 
'INSERT INTO '+@Datadest+'.'+@Schemaname+'.'+@Tablename +' ('+@columns +')
SELECT '+@columns +' FROM '+@Datasource+'.'+@Schemaname+'.'+@Tablename

PRINT @InserCmd
/*Execute the command*/
--EXECUTE sp_executesql @InserCmd
--ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score -2):

Something like this:

```
Insert into dbo.Newtbl 

SELECT * FROM dbo.OldTbl
```

Comment: No ! I want to keep the new schema of the new table !